# how can I write value as a string in assertion

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to verify the text using assertion. When I put the text as a String, I get an error that "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable. Can you please help?

```
Assert.assertTrue(By.id("area"), "var _config_adContentType = Number("0");");
```

Comment: `By.id("area")` instantiates a `By` object as far as I recall.

Comment: I am sorry, i want to inject this text as a String "var _config_adContentType = Number("0");"

Comment: escape quotation marks with \ `"var _config_adContentType = Number(\"0\");")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick tip would be putting your Number("0") in single quotes just like this: Number'(0'). Hope this can help you!

Answer (score 1):

AssertTrue(need a condition), I think you need assertequal(expected,actual)

Comment: u can make your object to String by object.toString()